# I need to write an expression to find the min and max value over the range A = c(10:1,20:11) using a for loop and if statement in R

Tags: r

I am new to `R` and we have a small assignment that I am struggling with. This is what I have so far and I don't understand why the code isn't working.

```
Max = 0

A = c(10:1,20:11)

for(i in A){if(A>i){A = Max}}
```

What is wrong and could someone briefly explain why?

Comment: It's wrong because it doesn't make sense -- you're comparing the entire vector A to individual elements of A and saying "If the vector A is greater than it's element i then vector A is the max".

Comment: `max(A)` is a thing.

Comment: @ZheyuanLi Oh, I see. Thanks!

Comment: I can't us max(). I have to use a for loop with an if statement

Comment: `sort(A, partial = length(A))[length(A)]` if you want a fast solution, though its `for` loops are in C.

Comment: Get yourself a better teacher if this one is teaching you loops instead of vectorization in R.

Answer (score 1):

While I agree with all the comments, the question

> *What is wrong and could someone briefly explain why?*

is still unanswered.

I've reformatted the code for readability:

```
A <- c(10:1, 20:11)
Max <- 0
for (i in A) {
  if (A > i) {
    A <- Max
  }
}
```

After the intial assignment, `A` is a vector containing the numbers

```
A
 [1] 10  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1 20 19 18 17 16 15 14 13 12 11
```

If we run the `for` loop we do get:

```
Warning messages:
1: In if (A > i) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
2: In if (A > i) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

which unfortunately had been left out by the OP.

`A` now holds only one value

```
A
[1] 0
```

which obviously isn't the maximum value of `A`.

#### Explanation

In the first iteration of the `for` loop `i` is assigned the first value in `A` which is 10. The condition of the `if` clause compares the entire vector `A` holding 20 elements with `i` which contains only one value but the `if` clause can take only one decision. This is signalled by the first warning message.

The `if` clause uses only the result of the first comparison, i.e., comparing the first element of `A` with `i`, (*10 > 10*) which is `FALSE`. The loop continues with the next iteration.

In the second iteration of the `for` loop `i` is assigned the second value in `A` which is 9. Again, a warning message is issued and the `if` clause uses only the result of the first comparison, i.e., comparing the first element of `A` with `i`. But now `i` is 9 and (*10 > 9*) is `TRUE`. Thus, the `if` clause gets executed and `A` is set to the value of `Max` which is 0.

From third iteration on, `A` contains only a single value 0 which is never changed again. Also, there are no more warnings as `A > i` returns only one result.